# Calling a global function defined in C++ source file , from a C source file

Tags: c++, c

Is there any way to call a C++ function from a C source file , without using extern "C" prior to the function declaration in the C++ file e.g :

```
//C++ source file

extern "C" void func_name();

void func_name()
{
.... 
}
```

Comment: Hint: What do you think `extern "C"` is for?

Comment: I know it works with extern "C", but my task is to try to make it without extern "C"

Comment: Why? The only way I can think of doing that is to call the mangled name from C. And I don't think you want to do that.

Comment: Why don't you want to use `extern "C"`? That's what it's for.

Comment: This is something like homework from the university where i study, and it is explicitly said,  to find if there is a way to do it without extern "C" in the declaration . (sorry for bad english)

Answer (score 2):

The only way to not use extern "C" directly is to manually determine the mangled name and call that from C; which is essentially just doing extern "C" but manually. There's no point or purpose or alternative method with any merit whatsoever.

Comment: I can think of at least three legitimate reasons to want to do this.  Also, "manually determining the mangled name" is _not_ "just doing extern 'C' manually"; it is the opposite.

Comment: Perhaps it is a homework assignment to learn how the C++ compiler decorates names.

Comment: Yes , its exactly a homework to learn about decorations in C++ .

Answer (score 2):

I'm not aware of any combination of C and C++ compilers that provide an officially supported way to do this.  You're supposed to use extern "C" in the C++-side header files.

However, perhaps you have to anyway; I can think of several reasons other than homework, such as when you've got a third-party C++ library with an interface that *could* be invoked from C but the developers neglected to put extern "C" in the headers, and you can't recompile it.

There *is* usually an unofficial way to do it: you have to find out the *mangled name* of the C++ function, and any hidden parameters that it has (`this` is almost always treated as a hidden first parameter, and there may be others).  You then write a declaration on the C side using the mangled name and the full parameter list.

Here is a very simple example that will work with GCC on most operating systems and CPUs:

```
/* file1.cpp */
#include <cstdio>
void foo()
{
    puts("hello from foo");
}

/* file2.c */
#include <stdio.h>
extern void _Z3foov(void);
int main(void)
{
    puts("hello from main");
    _Z3foov();
    return 0;
}
```

Because this is homework I am not going to give you a more complicated example, but I am going to point you at the so-called "[Itanium C++ ABI](https://itanium-cxx-abi.github.io/cxx-abi/)", which specifies how the mangling and the hidden parameters work with GCC and Clang on most operating systems and CPUs.  (Be aware that MSVC uses a *completely different*, undocumented, scheme.  I have heard rumors that Clang can optionally use MSVC's scheme now but I'm not sure I believe it, considering how gargantuan a reverse-engineering job it would have been. ;-)

(In case you're wondering, mangled names are how function and operator overloading are implemented in the linker.  If my `file1.cpp` had defined both `void foo(void)` and `void foo(int)`, that would have produced an object file exporting the mangled names `_Z3foov` and `_Z3fooi`.)

Comment: Apart from name mangling, it is also necessary to account for any difference in calling conventions and of layout of types, particularly `struct` or `class` types, that are passed as arguments or returned by the function.   The REASON that the standard encourages name mangling is that there is more to calling a C++ function than just matching function names, even if the conventional linker only requires names to match.

Answer (score 1):

You could write a separate translation unit, let's say `mycppunit.cpp` containing your `void func_name()` implementation without any `extern "C"` declarations. Compile this translation unit into a binary using a C++ compiler, yielding, for example, a `mycppunit.o` binary; then, use a command line tool like `nm` to find out how the function name has been mangled: For example:

```
nm mycppunit.o | grep func_name
```

would give something like

```
000000010006a920 T __Z9func_namev
```

Then you may assume that there will be a function `void _Z9func_namev()` available, and you can write in a translation unit, e.g. `my_c_program.c, the following:

```
void _Z9func_namev();

int main() {
    _Z9func_namev();
}
```

Compiling this with a C compiler and linking it together with the `mycppunit.o` will give the desired result.

Hope it is what you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, i did it but im using Visual Studio and the mangled name is ?func_name@@YAXXZ , but i cant write symbols like ? and @ in the code. What should i do ?